# How to align columns using tabularx?

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn

The table shown in the image has 24 columns and the texts do not fit in the cell. also the columns are not aligned and are not distributed along the width of the sheet.

[image]

the errors image

[image]

Here is the code and errors

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Pictures & Labels
%%\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox} %%este es para hacer ajustes automáticos de tablas
\usepackage{longtable} % tablas grandes 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{makecell}

% Paper Style
\usepackage[letterpaper,centering]{geometry} %%paquete para cambiar diseño de pagina
\usepackage[title,toc,page]{appendix}
%%\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
% like \newgeometry, but also allows change of landscape/portrait and paper size
% to be used with caution!
\newcommand{\newgeometryfull}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \Gm@restore@org
  \Gm@initnewgm
%  \Gm@newgmtrue
  \setkeys{Gm}{#1}%
%  \Gm@newgmfalse
  \Gm@process
  \ifnum\mag=\@m\else\Gm@magtooffset\fi
  \Gm@changelayout
  \Gm@showparams{newgeometry}}%
\makeatother

%% Allow A3 sheets - - establecemos las características del A3
\newenvironment{a3mypage}{%
    \newgeometryfull{paperwidth=431.8mm,paperheight=279.4mm,centering,hmargin=31.75mm,top=25.4 mm,bottom=25.4 mm}
    % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}
{  \restoregeometry
    % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth} %termina la edicion de la hoja A3
    
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries\color{blue}}


\begin{document}
\begin{a3mypage}
\section{Machine selecction}
{
%\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{m{0.172\linewidth}*{23}{X}} %%tabla
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.808,0.576,0.847} \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large TITULO:}}} & \multicolumn{23}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr23\hsize+141\tabcolsep}X}{\textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large DISEÑO DE UN DESHIDRATADOR TEXTURIZADOR AL VACÍO PARA DISMINUIR EL TIEMPO DE DESHIDRATADO CONSERVANDO LAS PROPIEDADES DEL AÇAÍ}}} \\
\multirow{2}{=}{Criterios de Diseño} & Peso & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Solar} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Bandejas} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Tunel} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Rodillo o Tambor} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Rotativo} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Lecho Fluidizado} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Spray} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Banda o Faja} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Vacío} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{DIC} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Liofilizador} \\
  & W*(\%) & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U \\
  numeros y decimales & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23\\
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.808,0.576,0.847}\hline
\end{tabularx}


}
\end{a3mypage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- number of columns in a `tabularx` table is limited to 20. If you like to have more, then you need to use fix of @David Carlisle (added in MWE below)
- I took a liberty and a little bit redesign your table:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Pictures & Labels
%%\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox} %%este es para hacer ajustes automáticos de tablas
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries\color{blue}}
 
\usepackage{xparse} % for case in used LaTEX system hasn't recent version of it
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\makeatletter % fix which once provide me @David Carlisle on chat
\def\TX@endtabularx{%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \TX@find@endtabularxa\csname end\TX@\endcsname
     \endtabularx\TX@\endtabularx\TX@find@endtabularxa
  \expandafter\TX@newcol\expandafter{\tabularxcolumn{\TX@col@width}}%
  \let\verb\TX@verb
  \def\@elt##1{\global\value{##1}\the\value{##1}\relax}%
  \edef\TX@ckpt{\cl@@ckpt}%
  \let\@elt\relax
  \TX@old@table\maxdimen
  \TX@col@width.5\TX@target%<<<<< smaller initial guess for big table
  \global\TX@cols\@ne
  \TX@typeout@
    {\@spaces Table Width\@spaces Column Width\@spaces X Columns}%
  \TX@trial{\def\NC@rewrite@X{%
          \global\advance\TX@cols\@ne\NC@find p{\TX@col@width}}}%
  \loop
    \TX@arith
    \ifTX@
    \TX@trial{}%
  \repeat
  {\let\@footnotetext\TX@ftntext\let\@xfootnotenext\TX@xftntext
    \csname tabular*\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter\TX@target
      \the\toks@
    \csname endtabular*\endcsname}%
  \global\TX@ftn\expandafter{\expandafter}\the\TX@ftn
  \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \TX@find@endtabularxbb
    \expandafter\end\expandafter{\TX@}%
    \endtabularx\TX@\endtabularx\TX@find@endtabularxb
}
\makeatother

% Paper Style
\usepackage[letterpaper,centering]{geometry} %%paquete para cambiar diseño de pagina
\usepackage[title,toc,page]{appendix}
%%\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
% like \newgeometry, but also allows change of landscape/portrait and paper size
% to be used with caution!
\newcommand{\newgeometryfull}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \Gm@restore@org
  \Gm@initnewgm
%  \Gm@newgmtrue
  \setkeys{Gm}{#1}%
%  \Gm@newgmfalse
  \Gm@process
  \ifnum\mag=\@m\else\Gm@magtooffset\fi
  \Gm@changelayout
  \Gm@showparams{newgeometry}}%
\makeatother

%% Allow A3 sheets - - establecemos las características del A3
\newenvironment{a3mypage}{%
 \newgeometryfull{paperwidth=431.8mm,paperheight=279.4mm,centering,hmargin=31.75mm,top=25.4 mm,bottom=25.4 mm}
    % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}
{  \restoregeometry
    % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth} %termina la edicion de la hoja A3


\begin{document}
\begin{a3mypage}
\section{Machine selecction}

\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{m{0.12\linewidth}*{23}{X}} %%tabla
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.808,0.576,0.847} 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large TITULO:}}} 
    & \multicolumn{23}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-0.12\linewidth-4\tabcolsep}}{
        \large\bfseries\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545} {DISEÑO DE UN DESHIDRATADOR TEXTURIZADOR AL VACÍO PARA DISMINUIR 
        EL TIEMPO DE DESHIDRATADO CONSERVANDO LAS PROPIEDADES DEL AÇAÍ}} \\
\multirow{2}{=}{Criterios de Diseño} 
    & Peso  & \mcc[2]{Solar}    & \mcc[2]{Bandejas}         & \mcc[2]{Tunel}  & \mcc[2]{Rodillo o Tambor} 
            & \mcc[2]{Rotativo} & \mcc[2]{Lecho Fluidizado} & \mcc[2]{Spray} & \mcc[2]{Banda o Faja} 
            & \mcc[2]{Vacío}    & \mcc[2]{DIC}              & \mcc[2]{Liofilizador} \\
    \cmidrule(l{1pt}r{1pt}){2-2}    
    \cmidrule(l{1pt}r{1pt}){3-4}\cmidrule(l{1pt}r{1pt}){5-6}\cmidrule(l{1pt}r{1pt}){7-8}\cmidrule(l{1pt}r{1pt}){9-10}
    \cmidrule(l{1pt}r{1pt}){11-12}\cmidrule(l{1pt}r{1pt}){13-14}\cmidrule(l{1pt}r{1pt}){15-16}\cmidrule(l{1pt}r{1pt}){17-18}
    \cmidrule(l{1pt}r{1pt}){19-20}\cmidrule(l{1pt}r{1pt}){21-22}\cmidrule(l{1pt}r{1pt}){23-24}
    & W*(\%) & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U \\
  numeros y decimales & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23\\
    \arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.808,0.576,0.847}
    \bottomrule%\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{a3mypage}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**

In table redesign I did the following:

- Define new command `\mcc` as shortness for `multicolumn{<...>}{c}{<...>}`.
- In table are added `\cmidrule(l1pt}{r{1pt}){...}` which indicate columns pairs with common headers.
- Remove package `colortbl` and instead it introduce option `table` at loading package `xcolor`, i.e. it is load now as `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`.
- In preamble load also package `xparse` for cases, when your LaTeX system (Overleaf) doesn't contain recent changes in LaTeX. This enable to use definition of `\mcc` also in older LaTeX version and not harm its new version.
- Provided code is tested by MiKTeX and by use of Overleaf.

After this changes and added fix for number of columns in table, your document compile fine, without any warnings or errors.

Obtained result can still be slightly improved. Some columns are wider than others because their headers is longer than defined with of `X` columns. So you my liked the following solution, which in comparison to the first one has the following changes:

- longer (multiword) column headers are written in two lines
- cells' contents are centered by use column type `C`,  which is defined by `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}`
- separation between `\cmidrule`s are increased to `2pt`that now is better visible
- in table is used normal font size

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Pictures & Labels
%%\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox} %%este es para hacer ajustes automáticos de tablas
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries\color{blue}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\makeatletter % fix which once provide me @David Carlisle on chat
\def\TX@endtabularx{%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \TX@find@endtabularxa\csname end\TX@\endcsname
     \endtabularx\TX@\endtabularx\TX@find@endtabularxa
  \expandafter\TX@newcol\expandafter{\tabularxcolumn{\TX@col@width}}%
  \let\verb\TX@verb
  \def\@elt##1{\global\value{##1}\the\value{##1}\relax}%
  \edef\TX@ckpt{\cl@@ckpt}%
  \let\@elt\relax
  \TX@old@table\maxdimen
  \TX@col@width.5\TX@target%<<<<< smaller initial guess for big table
  \global\TX@cols\@ne
  \TX@typeout@
    {\@spaces Table Width\@spaces Column Width\@spaces X Columns}%
  \TX@trial{\def\NC@rewrite@X{%
          \global\advance\TX@cols\@ne\NC@find p{\TX@col@width}}}%
  \loop
    \TX@arith
    \ifTX@
    \TX@trial{}%
  \repeat
  {\let\@footnotetext\TX@ftntext\let\@xfootnotenext\TX@xftntext
    \csname tabular*\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter\TX@target
      \the\toks@
    \csname endtabular*\endcsname}%
  \global\TX@ftn\expandafter{\expandafter}\the\TX@ftn
  \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \TX@find@endtabularxbb
    \expandafter\end\expandafter{\TX@}%
    \endtabularx\TX@\endtabularx\TX@find@endtabularxb
}
\makeatother

% Paper Style
\usepackage[letterpaper,centering]{geometry} %%paquete para cambiar diseño de pagina
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage[title,toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
% like \newgeometry, but also allows change of landscape/portrait and paper size
% to be used with caution!
\newcommand{\newgeometryfull}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \Gm@restore@org
  \Gm@initnewgm
%  \Gm@newgmtrue
  \setkeys{Gm}{#1}%
%  \Gm@newgmfalse
  \Gm@process
  \ifnum\mag=\@m\else\Gm@magtooffset\fi
  \Gm@changelayout
  \Gm@showparams{newgeometry}}%
\makeatother

%% Allow A3 sheets - - establecemos las características del A3
\newenvironment{a3mypage}{%
    \newgeometryfull{paperwidth=431.8mm,paperheight=279.4mm,centering,hmargin=31.75mm,top=25.4 mm,bottom=25.4 mm}
    % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}
    {  
    \restoregeometry
    % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth} %termina la edicion de la hoja A3


\begin{document}
\lipsum

\begin{a3mypage}
\section{Machine selecction}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{m{0.1\linewidth}*{23}{C}} %%tabla
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.808,0.576,0.847} 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large TITULO:}}} 
    & \multicolumn{23}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-0.1\linewidth-4\tabcolsep}}{
        \large\bfseries\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545} {DISEÑO DE UN DESHIDRATADOR TEXTURIZADOR AL VACÍO PARA DISMINUIR 
        EL TIEMPO DE DESHIDRATADO CONSERVANDO LAS PROPIEDADES DEL AÇAÍ}} \\
\multirow{2}{=}{Criterios de Diseño} 
    & Peso  & \mcc[2]{Solar}    & \mcc[2]{Bandejas} & \mcc[2]{Tunel}  & \mcc[2]{\makecell{Rodillo\\ o Tambor}} 
            & \mcc[2]{Rotativo} & \mcc[2]{\makecell{Lecho\\ Fluidizado}} 
                                                    & \mcc[2]{Spray} & \mcc[2]{\makecell{Banda\\ o Faja}} 
            & \mcc[2]{Vacío}    & \mcc[2]{DIC}              & \mcc[2]{Liofilizador} \\
    \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){2-2}
    \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){3-4}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){5-6}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){7-8}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){9-10}
    \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){11-12}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){13-14}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){15-16}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){17-18}
    \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){19-20}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){21-22}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){23-24}
    & W*(\%) & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U & S & U \\
  numeros y decimales & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23\\
    \arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.808,0.576,0.847}
    \bottomrule%\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{a3mypage}
\end{document}
```

which produce

[image]

Comment: I am using overleaf and it shows me a lot of errors during compilation

Comment: @ReyesReyesEmerzon, Overleaf hasn't recent version of packages,  so some problem can arises. I didn't test on it. Using local installation of (almost) recent MiKTeX works fine.

Comment: @ReyesReyesEmerzon, I just tested my solution on Overleaf. As I said, it hasn't recent version of LaTeX, consequently using it, you need to insert into preamble before `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` code line `\usepackage{xparse}`.  Inserting this, Compilation hasn't any warning or error- See edited answer.

Comment: is there any way to fix this as i am new to latex and want to understand all possible cases. What is the problem in this?