# how can i remove whitespace and prevent words in column in table from disappearing?

Tags: tables, tcolorbox, multirow

In the table shown in the image (follow-up to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602774) question), there are blank spaces that I want to remove, as well as prevent the letters in the first column from disappearing. I have also tried to justify it to the left in the first column and I have not been able to.[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Pictures & Labels
%%\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox} %%este es para hacer ajustes automáticos de tablas
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\makeatletter % fix which once provide me @David Carlisle on chat
\def\TX@endtabularx{%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \TX@find@endtabularxa\csname end\TX@\endcsname
     \endtabularx\TX@\endtabularx\TX@find@endtabularxa
  \expandafter\TX@newcol\expandafter{\tabularxcolumn{\TX@col@width}}%
  \let\verb\TX@verb
  \def\@elt##1{\global\value{##1}\the\value{##1}\relax}%
  \edef\TX@ckpt{\cl@@ckpt}%
  \let\@elt\relax
  \TX@old@table\maxdimen
  \TX@col@width.5\TX@target%<<<<< smaller initial guess for big table
  \global\TX@cols\@ne
  \TX@typeout@
    {\@spaces Table Width\@spaces Column Width\@spaces X Columns}%
  \TX@trial{\def\NC@rewrite@X{%
          \global\advance\TX@cols\@ne\NC@find p{\TX@col@width}}}%
  \loop
    \TX@arith
    \ifTX@
    \TX@trial{}%
  \repeat
  {\let\@footnotetext\TX@ftntext\let\@xfootnotenext\TX@xftntext
    \csname tabular*\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter\TX@target
      \the\toks@
    \csname endtabular*\endcsname}%
  \global\TX@ftn\expandafter{\expandafter}\the\TX@ftn
  \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \TX@find@endtabularxbb
    \expandafter\end\expandafter{\TX@}%
    \endtabularx\TX@\endtabularx\TX@find@endtabularxb
}
%\makeatother

% Paper Style
\usepackage[letterpaper,centering]{geometry} %%paquete para cambiar diseño de pagina
%\usepackage[title,toc,page]{appendix}
%%\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
% like \newgeometry, but also allows change of landscape/portrait and paper size
% to be used with caution!
\newcommand{\newgeometryfull}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \Gm@restore@org
  \Gm@initnewgm
%  \Gm@newgmtrue
  \setkeys{Gm}{#1}%
%  \Gm@newgmfalse
  \Gm@process
  \ifnum\mag=\@m\else\Gm@magtooffset\fi
  \Gm@changelayout
  \Gm@showparams{newgeometry}}%
\makeatother

%% Allow A3 sheets - - establecemos las características del A3
\newenvironment{a3mypage}{%
    \newgeometryfull{paperwidth=431.8mm,paperheight=279.4mm,centering,hmargin=31.75mm,top=25.4 mm,bottom=25.4 mm}
    % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}
{  \restoregeometry
    % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth} %termina la edicion de la hoja A3

\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries\color{blue}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}
\begin{a3mypage}
\section{Machine selecction}

\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.557,0.141,0.667}
\newcommand{\myti}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\linti}[2]{\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){#1-#2}}
{\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{0.996\linewidth}{|p{0.15\linewidth}*{23}{C}|} %%tabla
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.808,0.576,0.847} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{\textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large TITULO:}}} & \multicolumn{23}{p{\dimexpr 0.996\linewidth-0.15\linewidth-4\tabcolsep}|}{\large\bfseries\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545} {DISEÑO DE UN DESHIDRATADOR TEXTURIZADOR AL VACÍO PARA DISMINUIR EL TIEMPO DE DESHIDRATADO CONSERVANDO LAS PROPIEDADES DEL AÇAÍ}}\\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}\multirow{2}{=}{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large\textbf{Criterios de diseño}}} 
& \textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large\textbf{Peso}}  
& \mcc[2]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large\textbf{Solar}}}    
& \mcc[2]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large\textbf{Bandejas}}} 
& \mcc[2]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large\textbf{Túnel}}}  
& \mcc[2]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large\textbf{\makecell{Rodillo o\\Tambor}}}}
& \mcc[2]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large\textbf{Rotativo}}} 
& \mcc[2]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large\textbf{\makecell{Lecho\\Fluidizado}}}} 
& \mcc[2]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large\textbf{Spray}}} 
& \mcc[2]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large\textbf{\makecell{Banda o\\Faja}}}} 
& \mcc[2]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large\textbf{Vacío}}}    
& \mcc[2]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large\textbf{DIC}}} 
& \mcc[2]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.545}{\large\textbf{Liofilizador}}}\\
\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){2-2}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){3-4}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){5-6}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){7-8}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){9-10}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){11-12}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){13-14}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){15-16}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){17-18}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){19-20}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){21-22}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){23-24}
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} & \myti{P(\%)} & \myti{S} & \myti{U} & \myti{S} & \myti{U} & \myti{S} & \myti{U} & \myti{S} & \myti{U} & \myti{S} & \myti{U} & \myti{S} & \myti{U} & \myti{S} & \myti{U} & \myti{S} & \myti{U}& \myti{S} & \myti{U} & \myti{S} & \myti{U} & \myti{S} & \myti{U} \\\bottomrule%\hline
%%star to table content
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.882,0.745,0.906} \thead{Calidad del producto final} & 40\% &  & 2.15 &  & 1.8 &  & 1.9 &  & 1.9 &  & 2.05 &  & 3.5 &  & 2 &  & 2.35 &  & 3.7 &  & 3.9 &  & 4 \\
Propiedades nutricionales y antioxidantes & 15\% & 6 & 0.9 & 4 & 0.6 & 3 & 0.45 & 4 & 0.6 & 4 & 0.6 & 5 & 0.75 & 4 & 0.6 & 5 & 0.75 & 9 & 1.35 & 10 & 1.5 & 10 & 1.5 \\
Propiedades sensoriales & 15\% & 5 & 0.75 & 4 & 0.6 & 5 & 0.75 & 4 & 0.6 & 5 & 0.75 & 5 & 0.75 & 4 & 0.6 & 6 & 0.9 & 9 & 1.35 & 10 & 1.5 & 10 & 1.5 \\
Contenido de humedad & 10\% & 5 & 0.5 & 6 & 0.6 & 7 & 0.7 & 7 & 0.7 & 7 & 0.7 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 0.8 & 7 & 0.7 & 10 & 1 & 9 & 0.9 & 10 & 1 \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.882,0.745,0.906} \thead{Costo de la tecnología} & 30\% &  & 2.75 &  & 2.3 &  & 1.1 &  & 2.8 &  & 1.35 &  & 1.55 &  & 3.2 &  & 0.95 &  & 1.95 &  & 1.5 &  & 1.25 \\
Costo de fabricación & 15\% & 9 & 1.35 & 7 & 1.05 & 2 & 0.3 & 4 & 0.6 & 4 & 0.6 & 4 & 0.6 & 7 & 1.05 & 2 & 0.3 & 6 & 0.9 & 5 & 0.75 & 4 & 0.6 \\
Costo de instalación & 5\% & 9 & 0.45 & 8 & 0.4 & 5 & 0.25 & 5 & 0.25 & 4 & 0.2 & 6 & 0.3 & 7 & 0.35 & 2 & 0.1 & 9 & 0.45 & 4 & 0.2 & 4 & 0.2 \\
Costo de operación & 5\% & 10 & 0.5 & 9 & 0.45 & 7 & 0.35 & 7 & 0.35 & 7 & 0.35 & 6 & 0.3 & 8 & 0.4 & 6 & 0.3 & 6 & 0.3 & 6 & 0.3 & 5 & 0.25 \\
Costo de mantenimiento & 5\% & 9 & 0.45 & 8 & 0.4 & 4 & 0.2 & 4 & 1.6 & 4 & 0.2 & 7 & 0.35 & 7 & 1.4 & 5 & 0.25 & 6 & 0.3 & 5 & 0.25 & 4 & 0.2 \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.882,0.745,0.906} \thead{Características técnicas de la tecnología} & 25\% &  & 0.75 &  & 1.25 &  & 1.4 &  & 1.4 &  & 1.4 &  & 1.25 &  & 1.3 &  & 1.45 &  & 1.65 &  & 1.8 &  & 1.45 \\
Tiempo de deshidratado & 10\% & 2 & 0.2 & 6 & 0.6 & 8 & 0.8 & 8 & 0.8 & 8 & 0.8 & 7 & 0.7 & 8 & 0.8 & 8 & 0.8 & 8 & 0.8 & 10 & 1 & 8 & 0.8 \\
Eficiencia y productividad & 5\% & 4 & 0.2 & 5 & 0.25 & 7 & 0.35 & 7 & 0.35 & 7 & 0.35 & 6 & 0.3 & 6 & 0.3 & 8 & 0.4 & 8 & 0.4 & 7 & 0.35 & 4 & 0.2 \\
Variedad de productos & 5\% & 7 & 0.35 & 8 & 0.4 & 5 & 0.25 & 5 & 0.25 & 5 & 0.25 & 5 & 0.25 & 4 & 0.2 & 5 & 0.25 & 9 & 0.45 & 9 & 0.45 & 9 & 0.45 \\
Compatibilidad con procesos & 5\% & 5 & 0.25 & 6 & 0.3 & 5 & 0.25 & 5 & 0.25 & 5 & 0.25 & 6 & 0.3 & 6 & 0.3 & 6 & 0.3 & 9 & 0.45 & 9 & 0.45 & 9 & 0.45 \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.882,0.745,0.906}\thead{Grado de I+D+i} & 5\% & 4 & 0.2 & 6 & 0.3 & 6 & 0.3 & 6 & 0.3 & 6 & 0.3 & 5 & 0.25 & 7 & 0.35 & 6 & 0.3 & 8 & 0.4 & 10 & 0.5 & 10 & 0.5 \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
Utilidad global de selección (UGS) & 100\% &  & 5.85 &  & 5.65 &  & 4.7 &  & 6.4 &  & 5.1 &  & 6.55 &  & 6.85 &  & 5.05 &  & 7.7 &  & 7.7 &  & 7.2\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{a3mypage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

- your question is actually follow-up question of your previous. It will be helpful if you would mentioned this in your question and provide link to it.
- white space is caused by use of `makecell`, which not cover cells' `\tabcolsep`. A remedy for this is define new command, which mimic `makecell` and cover also `tabcolsep` (in MWE below is named `\MC`)
- In MWE below is done the following changes:

  - instead `\makecell` is used new define `MC`
  - to `color` is added option `svgnames` and for text color used color `DrakBlue`. SImilarly can be select colors for row colors (I didn't bother with this)
  - using `thead` in `multirow` cells disable text breaking in cell, consequently some text was not visible. In such  cases I manually break text into two lines
  - to the first column is added option `\RaggedRight`

I strongly encourage you to loo (and learn from) [How to write nice tables](https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/). Also try to better group loading of packages and defined new commands. Now is easy to get lost in your preamble ...

**Edit:**
In codes inserted small tweaks (as adjustment of column width, new which adopt it to Overleaf capability -- lack of recent versions of used packages) as well are added two new multi column commands with vertical lines on the front and the end respectively:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Pictures & Labels
%%\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox} %%este es para hacer ajustes automáticos de tablas
\usepackage{float}
%%%% changed + new
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor} 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.557,0.141,0.667}                                             % <-------
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\MC{m}{\begin{tabular}{@{} c @{}}#1\end{tabular}}  % <-------
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{2}m}{%                                      % <-------
    \multicolumn{#1}{>{\large\bfseries}c}{\textcolor{DarkBlue}{\MC{#2}}}        % <-------
                                         }   
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcF{O{2}m}{%                                      % <-------
    \multicolumn{#1}{|>{\large\bfseries}c}{\textcolor{DarkBlue}{\MC{#2}}}       % <-------
                                         } \NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcL{O{2}m}{%                                      % <-------
    \multicolumn{#1}{>{\large\bfseries}c|}{\textcolor{DarkBlue}{\MC{#2}}}       % <-------
                                         }
%%%%
\makeatletter % fix which once provide me @David Carlisle on chat
\def\TX@endtabularx{%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \TX@find@endtabularxa\csname end\TX@\endcsname
     \endtabularx\TX@\endtabularx\TX@find@endtabularxa
  \expandafter\TX@newcol\expandafter{\tabularxcolumn{\TX@col@width}}%
  \let\verb\TX@verb
  \def\@elt##1{\global\value{##1}\the\value{##1}\relax}%
  \edef\TX@ckpt{\cl@@ckpt}%
  \let\@elt\relax
  \TX@old@table\maxdimen
  \TX@col@width.5\TX@target%<<<<< smaller initial guess for big table
  \global\TX@cols\@ne
  \TX@typeout@
    {\@spaces Table Width\@spaces Column Width\@spaces X Columns}%
  \TX@trial{\def\NC@rewrite@X{%
          \global\advance\TX@cols\@ne\NC@find p{\TX@col@width}}}%
  \loop
    \TX@arith
    \ifTX@
    \TX@trial{}%
  \repeat
  {\let\@footnotetext\TX@ftntext\let\@xfootnotenext\TX@xftntext
    \csname tabular*\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter\TX@target
      \the\toks@
    \csname endtabular*\endcsname}%
  \global\TX@ftn\expandafter{\expandafter}\the\TX@ftn
  \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \TX@find@endtabularxbb
    \expandafter\end\expandafter{\TX@}%
    \endtabularx\TX@\endtabularx\TX@find@endtabularxb
}
%\makeatother

% Paper Style
\usepackage[letterpaper,centering]{geometry} %%paquete para cambiar diseño de pagina
%\usepackage[title,toc,page]{appendix}
%%\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
% like \newgeometry, but also allows change of landscape/portrait and paper size
% to be used with caution!
\newcommand{\newgeometryfull}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \Gm@restore@org
  \Gm@initnewgm
%  \Gm@newgmtrue
  \setkeys{Gm}{#1}%
%  \Gm@newgmfalse
  \Gm@process
  \ifnum\mag=\@m\else\Gm@magtooffset\fi
  \Gm@changelayout
  \Gm@showparams{newgeometry}}%
\makeatother

%% Allow A3 sheets - - establecemos las características del A3
\newenvironment{a3mypage}{%
    \newgeometryfull{paperwidth=431.8mm,paperheight=279.4mm,centering,hmargin=31.75mm,top=25.4 mm,bottom=25.4 mm}
    % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}
{  \restoregeometry
    % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth} %termina la edicion de la hoja A3

\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries\color{blue}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{a3mypage}
\section{Machine selection}
\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}

{\centering
 \small
 \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\RaggedRight}p{0.14\linewidth}*{11}{C} 
                                                              *{2}{>{\hsize=1.1\hsize}C}
                                                              *{2}{>{\hsize=0.9\hsize}C}
                                                              *{8}{C}|} %%tabla
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.808,0.576,0.847}
\mcF[1]{TITULO:}
    & \multicolumn{23}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-0.14\linewidth-4\tabcolsep}|}{\large\bfseries\textcolor{DarkBlue} {DISEÑO DE UN DESHIDRATADOR TEXTURIZADOR AL VACÍO PARA DISMINUIR EL TIEMPO DE DESHIDRATADO CONSERVANDO LAS PROPIEDADES DEL AÇAÍ}}\\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961}
\mcF[1]{\multirow[t]{2}{*}{\MC{Criterios\\ de diseño}}}
& \mcc[1]{Peso}
& \mcc{Solar}
& \mcc{Bandejas}
& \mcc{Túnel}
& \mcc{Rodillo\\ Tambor}
& \mcc{Rotativo}
& \mcc{Lecho\\ Fluidizado}
& \mcc{Spray}
& \mcc{Banda\\ o Faja}
& \mcc{Vacío}
& \mcc{DIC}
& \mcL{Liofili-\\zador}\\
%
    \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){2-2}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){3-4}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){5-6}
    \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){7-8}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){9-10}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){11-12}
    \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){13-14}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){15-16}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){17-18}
    \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){19-20}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){21-22}\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){23-24}
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.953,0.898,0.961} 
    & \MC{P(\%)} & \MC{S} & \MC{U} & \MC{S} & \MC{U} & \MC{S} & \MC{U} & \MC{S} & \MC{U} & \MC{S} & \MC{U} & \MC{S} & \MC{U} & \MC{S} & \MC{U} & \MC{S} & \MC{U}& \MC{S} & \MC{U} & \MC{S} & \MC{U} & \MC{S} & \MC{U} \\\bottomrule%\hline
%%start of table content
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.882,0.745,0.906} 
\thead{Calidad del\\ producto final} 
    & 40\% &  & 2.15 &  & 1.8 &  & 1.9 &  & 1.9 &  & 2.05 &  & 3.5 &  & 2 &  & 2.35 &  & 3.7 &  & 3.9 &  & 4 \\
Propiedades nutricionales y antioxidantes 
    & 15\% & 6 & 0.9 & 4 & 0.6 & 3 & 0.45 & 4 & 0.6 & 4 & 0.6 & 5 & 0.75 & 4 & 0.6 & 5 & 0.75 & 9 & 1.35 & 10 & 1.5 & 10 & 1.5 \\
Propiedades sensoriales 
    & 15\% & 5 & 0.75 & 4 & 0.6 & 5 & 0.75 & 4 & 0.6 & 5 & 0.75 & 5 & 0.75 & 4 & 0.6 & 6 & 0.9 & 9 & 1.35 & 10 & 1.5 & 10 & 1.5 \\
Contenido de humedad 
    & 10\% & 5 & 0.5 & 6 & 0.6 & 7 & 0.7 & 7 & 0.7 & 7 & 0.7 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 0.8 & 7 & 0.7 & 10 & 1 & 9 & 0.9 & 10 & 1 \\
    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.882,0.745,0.906} 
\thead{Costo de la tecnología} 
    & 30\% &  & 2.75 &  & 2.3 &  & 1.1 &  & 2.8 &  & 1.35 &  & 1.55 &  & 3.2 &  & 0.95 &  & 1.95 &  & 1.5 &  & 1.25 \\
Costo de fabricación 
    & 15\% & 9 & 1.35 & 7 & 1.05 & 2 & 0.3 & 4 & 0.6 & 4 & 0.6 & 4 & 0.6 & 7 & 1.05 & 2 & 0.3 & 6 & 0.9 & 5 & 0.75 & 4 & 0.6 \\
Costo de instalación 
    & 5\% & 9 & 0.45 & 8 & 0.4 & 5 & 0.25 & 5 & 0.25 & 4 & 0.2 & 6 & 0.3 & 7 & 0.35 & 2 & 0.1 & 9 & 0.45 & 4 & 0.2 & 4 & 0.2 \\
Costo de operación 
    & 5\% & 10 & 0.5 & 9 & 0.45 & 7 & 0.35 & 7 & 0.35 & 7 & 0.35 & 6 & 0.3 & 8 & 0.4 & 6 & 0.3 & 6 & 0.3 & 6 & 0.3 & 5 & 0.25 \\
Costo de mantenimiento 
    & 5\% & 9 & 0.45 & 8 & 0.4 & 4 & 0.2 & 4 & 1.6 & 4 & 0.2 & 7 & 0.35 & 7 & 1.4 & 5 & 0.25 & 6 & 0.3 & 5 & 0.25 & 4 & 0.2 \\
    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.882,0.745,0.906} 
\thead{Características técnicas\\ de la tecnología} 
    & 25\% &  & 0.75 &  & 1.25 &  & 1.4 &  & 1.4 &  & 1.4 &  & 1.25 &  & 1.3 &  & 1.45 &  & 1.65 &  & 1.8 &  & 1.45 \\
Tiempo de deshidratado 
    & 10\% & 2 & 0.2 & 6 & 0.6 & 8 & 0.8 & 8 & 0.8 & 8 & 0.8 & 7 & 0.7 & 8 & 0.8 & 8 & 0.8 & 8 & 0.8 & 10 & 1 & 8 & 0.8 \\
Eficiencia y productividad 
    & 5\% & 4 & 0.2 & 5 & 0.25 & 7 & 0.35 & 7 & 0.35 & 7 & 0.35 & 6 & 0.3 & 6 & 0.3 & 8 & 0.4 & 8 & 0.4 & 7 & 0.35 & 4 & 0.2 \\
Variedad de productos 
    & 5\% & 7 & 0.35 & 8 & 0.4 & 5 & 0.25 & 5 & 0.25 & 5 & 0.25 & 5 & 0.25 & 4 & 0.2 & 5 & 0.25 & 9 & 0.45 & 9 & 0.45 & 9 & 0.45 \\
Compatibilidad con procesos 
    & 5\% & 5 & 0.25 & 6 & 0.3 & 5 & 0.25 & 5 & 0.25 & 5 & 0.25 & 6 & 0.3 & 6 & 0.3 & 6 & 0.3 & 9 & 0.45 & 9 & 0.45 & 9 & 0.45 \\
     &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.882,0.745,0.906}
\thead{Grado de I+D+i} 
    & 5\% & 4 & 0.2 & 6 & 0.3 & 6 & 0.3 & 6 & 0.3 & 6 & 0.3 & 5 & 0.25 & 7 & 0.35 & 6 & 0.3 & 8 & 0.4 & 10 & 0.5 & 10 & 0.5 \\
Utilidad global de selección (UGS)
     & 100\% &  & 5.85 &  & 5.65 &  & 4.7 &  & 6.4 &  & 5.1 &  & 6.55 &  & 6.85 &  & 5.05 &  & 7.7 &  & 7.7 &  & 7.2\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{a3mypage}
\end{document}
```

Image is now copied from Overleaf:

[image]

Comment: when i work in overleaf i still have blank spaces in the middle.

Comment: @ReyesReyesEmerzon, see edited answer. Let me noted that you will have much less troubles if you install own LaTeX system ...